# How to implement thread inside a web service?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

I need to make a thread inside my web service, to check on some data in my database every specific time.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do that. The thread would die with the application pool. Create a windows service which checks the database using a `Thread` or a `Timer`.

Comment: "server" => "service", I assume. I would suggest to just create a console application and run it as a Scheduled Task in Windows. I do this all the time, and very rarely use a service. It's much easier to develop and deploy without services :-)

Comment: i need my web service to check every 5 min on db then send the data to c# client through TCP , and the database in only accessible from this web service

Comment: @ToDayIsNow, your question does not seem to reflect what you really want to ask.  Please update your question.

Comment: A webservice is stateless. There are no open connections which can let you send stuff back in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that?

If your service is per-call (i.e. not singleton), all the resources involved in servicing a request is supposed to be released right after the call.  If you spawn a thread, the request will be kept alive until your thread completes.

Also, checking on data in a database periodically does not really make sense in a *web service* call, which should complete within a very short time anyway, otherwise you kill scalability.

You're probably referring to a singleton web service, in that one single server object services requests.  In this case, you'll need to create the singleton object first -- most likely in a Windows service that is started automatically.

Your database polling is most likely used to cache certain popular values so that servicing requests do not need to hit the database itself.  In this case, your service is actually a middle-tier layer.  Unless you know that data in the database changes very frequently, consider replacing the database polling with triggers in the database that calls the web service to update new data.